# Issue while sending special characters in ajax post request

Tags: java, ajax, servlets, jquery

I am facing an issue while sending special characters in ajax POST request, these special characters are not received properly by my servlet where the request is sent.
Javascript code:

```
myAjaxPostrequest=new GetXmlHttpObject();
var parameters1="content="+mainContent;
    myAjaxPostrequest.open("POST", "controller", true);
    myAjaxPostrequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    myAjaxPostrequest.send(parameters1);
```

Servlet code:

```
String lsContentToSave = aoReq.getParameter("content");
System.out.println(lsContentToSave);
```

`aoReq` is HttpServletRequest object.

For eg. if the special character is `»` it prints `Â»`

I have also tried jquery post and still facing the same issue. Please let me know the fix for this.

Comment: Have you attempted specifying the `Content-type` header value as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8` instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: @Vineet Reynolds: That worked !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You tagged `jquery-ajax`, but the JS code in your question isn't recognizeable as jQuery. Are you *really* using [jQuery](http://jquery.org)? That look more like a ripoff of the poor w3schools tutorial.

In any way, you need to take the character encoding into account in 2 places. In the client side, when you form-encode the parameter, you should be using [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent). This will apply [percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) using UTF-8.

```js
var parameters = "content=" + encodeURIComponent(mainContent);
// ...
```

In the server side, **before** you get any parameter from the request body, you should set the request encoding to UTF-8 as follows:

```java
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
// ...

String content = request.getParameter("content");
// ...
```

---

That said, if you were really using jQuery, then you don't need to worry about using `encodeURIComponent()` in the client side. jQuery will handle it all for you if you're using [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) function with a data object.

```js
$.post('controller', { 'content': mainContent}, function() {
    // Callback function here.
});
```